# Rails render custom option

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am wondering how can I add **X-Robots-Tag** to response header with render. I need this tag to cause Google not to index this page, and if it's already indexed remove it from index

For more information [X-Robots-Tag](http://code.google.com/web/controlcrawlindex/docs/robots_meta_tag.html).

In documentation I didn't find such option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try `response.headers` as shown [here](http://work.j832.com/2008/10/ruby-rails-render-and-content-type-http.html)?

```
response.headers["X-Robots-Tag"] = 'noindex'
```